Binary quadratic problems benchmark set
I'm looking for a benchmark set of instances that are formulated as binary quadratic problems, i.e.
$$\min_{x\in \{0,1\}^n} x^TQx,\quad Ax\le b,\quad A_0x = b_0 \ .$$
The particular case of binary linear programming (with diagonal $Q$) are also of interest.
Would be nice to have the problems ranging from easy to challenging even for SOTA solvers, of diverse nature. Ideally, the problems should also be industrially relevant and their origin possible to track.

I was testing on Quadratic Assignment Problems, there is a QAPLIB you can have a look. I think the formulation is same as your problem setting. FYI.
https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/data-sets/qaplib/qaplib-problem-instances-and-solutions/

Looks very useful, thanks! As far as I know, quadratic assignment problems involve a very specific set of constraints $\sum_i{x_{ij}}=\sum_j{x_{ij}}=1$. Any chance you are aware of a more general benchmark set?

@WeatherReport I didn't user other benchmarks, but I just found QKPLIB, it could be useful as well. https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/82pxy6yv49/1
